# Does numpy.dot have accuracy limitations for large arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Does numpy.dot become wrong for large arrays? I am using an iMac with a 4 GHz Intel Core i7 and 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3. I have performed a simple experiment to compare the sum of squares from 1 through a large number using a for loop vs vectorization. When the the sum is large enough, the vectorization approach is wrong.  See the experiment below:

```
i = 3024617
sum([j**2 for j in range(1,i)]) - np.dot(np.arange(1,i,dtype=np.int64), np.arange(1,i, dtype=np.int64))

i = 3024618
sum([j**2 for j in range(1,i)]) - np.dot(np.arange(1,i,dtype=np.int64), np.arange(1,i, dtype=np.int64))
```

The first difference--and the difference for any i < 3024617 is 0

The second difference--and the difference for any i >= 3024618 is a large integer

I expect this difference to be 0 for all integers i.

Comment: Probably overflow

Comment: The `np.dot` with `x=np.arange(1,i,dtype=object)` matches the Python sum.  It's also quite a bit slower than the `np.int64` version.

Comment: The same thing happens if I don't use dtype=np.int64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python integers are unbounded.  `int64` is limited to what a signed 64-bit integer can represent:

```
>>> i = 3024617
>>> x = sum([j**2 for j in range(1,i)])
>>> x
9223371388520336796
>>> hex(x)
'0x7fffff690c418d9c'
>>> x.bit_length()
63
```

So that sum just fits in a signed 64-bit integer.  Add in `i**2` too, and it no longer does:

```
>>> x += i**2
>>> hex(x)
'0x800007bb0de78dad'
>>> x.bit_length()
64
```

It's not possible to represent that sum faithfully in a signed 64-bit integer.